# Lost passport with a valid visa on it, replaced passport, then found it

Tags: visas, usa, lost-documents

I lost my passport with a valid US visa on it. I informed the US embassy about it and got a new passport. After a few months, I found my old lost passport with the valid US visa on it.

Can I now travel to the US on the basis of the valid US visa stamped on my old passport, while carrying both the old and new passports together?

---

If not, what should I do now? I will have to apply for the visa again, and go through the hassle of filling up the form, submitting the visa fee, going to the embassy, etc. And I am not even sure whether they will give the visa again.

Comment: @JoeBlow An expired passport is very different from a lost/stolen passport.  If you present a lost/stolen passport to a US border official, they will probably assume it is stolen and that you are the thief.

Comment: @JoeBlow Also note that some visas may automatically expire if the passport does. I have some that specifically say "valid for twelve months as long as the passport remains valid".

Comment: Even if the Visa remained valid... do you really want to risk presenting a passport that -- for all you know --- could have been used by criminals or terrorists _to an US official_? Really?

Comment: No! Don't do this! Destroy the passport you reported as lost.

Comment: What country's passport did you temporarily lose?

Comment: @TheMathemagician: It would be a mistake to _destroy_ the old passport -- it does contain the (now invalid) US visa, after all, which might be useful when applying for a new visa. All the OP has to do is to _cancel_ it by physically mutilating it. The document [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118594/cancellation-of-passports.pdf) describes how British passports are cancelled. TL/DR: cut off the top right corners of the front and back covers, and the biodata page.

Comment: @TonyK that document is a set of instructions for UK officials.  Nobody should ever do that to their own passport.

Comment: @TonyK As phoog says, you shouldn't do that yourself. If you find your lost British passport, you should return it to the passport office, who will deal with it. in any case, we don't know if the passport in question is even a British passport -- and it probably isn't, given that British people don't need a visa for "ordinary" visits to the USA.

Answer (score 26):

No you cannot travel with your old visa

> If you have already reported your visa lost/stolen to the U.S. Embassy or Consulate, and then you later find your misplaced visa, then your visa will be invalid for future travel to the United States.  Therefore, in that situation you must apply for a new visa at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate.

[SOURCE](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/lost-or-stolen-travel-documents.html)

Comment: Worth mentioning what happens to visas for other countries. Are they generally invalidated too?

Comment: Whether the visa is valid or not is the wrong question. Whether you want to be found travelling on a cancelled passport, incarcerated, returned to your point of origin and banned from the US for 5 years is the right question. That is what may happen if you try to use a passport reported as lost.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: I don't think the OP was intending any form of deception. I think they want to know whether it's OK to use the new passport for travel, and the US visa in the old passport for entry to the US. (And DumbCoder's quote proves that the answer is no.)

Comment: @Mehrdad There are over 200 countries in the world. That's far too much data to list in response to a question that explicitly asks about US visas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I mean if even 80% of them behave a certain way then it's useful to let people know. You don't need to make a list.

Comment: @Mehrdad It's not useful at all. Knowing that 80% of countries do something doesn't tell you whether the specific country you're interested in does that thing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It does actually. It tells you you should probably worry. On the other hand if only 2% of them did then you'd know it's probably something obscure and some people would find it worth risking. Of course if your risk tolerance is so low then that's a different matter, but a lot of people look at this from a more practical standpoint.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the OP intended deception. Everyone rejected for deception claims it wasn't intentional. Thus, immigration officers around tend to assume every instance of deception is intentional.

Comment: @Mehrdad From a practical standpoint, committing immigration offences is typically a serious problem for future travel. Guessing the answer to a question about visa validity based on "some proportion of countries do it this way so, on the balance of probabilities, I guess the country I'm trying to go to in also does that" really is a very bad idea.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Why? I mean, you are using a stolen passport, and they don't know who stole it. That's clearly wrong, but who do they ban for 5 years?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I don't care if it's a bad idea, I'm just telling you some people have a different risk tolerance than you and it can be very much worth it to them. If you don't agree then don't argue or try to convince me, it's not something I'm trying to do. I'm just telling you a fact.

Comment: @Mehrdad And I'm telling you that there's no point in trying to compile data that could only be used to make bad decisions.