# Lost passport with US visa, reported lost passport but not the visa, later found passport

Tags: visas, passports, lost-documents

I lost my passport and reported it to the police. It had a US visa in it. I neglected to report the lost visa to the embassy. I replaced the passport and later found the old passport with the visa on it.

Can I still use the old US visa or do I have to get a new one too?

I am asking because I don't know what to do about never reporting the visa as lost. Would it look suspicious?

Comment: @pnuts: It's fine to have a visa in an old passport, but you would normally have to present both the old and new passport when entering the US.  If the old one is not punched or visibly invalidated, I think it would look suspicious.

Comment: Can you contact the police or foreign ministry and get the old passport punched, as would normally be done when you get it renewed?  Then you can present both passports when entering the US and everything will look normal.

Comment: You need to check your country's rules for handling lost, replaced, and then found passports. For example, if I lost my UK passport, I would have to complete a declaration including "I understand that completing and returning this form will result in the related passport being cancelled, that it must never be used again and, if subsequently found, it should be returned to Her Majesty’s Passport Office."

Comment: You should call the US consulate and ask them.  @NateEldredge taking about what "looks normal" makes it sound like you're advising an attempt to "get away with" using the visa despite the circumstances. This is fraught with danger.  The formerly lost passport may be checked against databases, and the presence or absence of punched holes doesn't affect its legal status.  Either the visa remains valid or not, and the only authority who can say which is the US.

Comment: @phoog The authority that issued the formerly lost passport also has a say in what should happen to it on being found.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that is of course true, but I doubt that the US would fail to accept a visa solely because it is in a passport that should have been returned to the British passport office. That is of course pure speculation, so if it were me I would ask the US consulate and do what they tell me to do.

Comment: @phoog It's hard to get in touch with the consulate. I've tried emailing and only got automated responses. I'm not sure I can use other means to contact them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost passport with a valid visa on it, replaced passport, then found it](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78455/lost-passport-with-a-valid-visa-on-it-replaced-passport-then-found-it)

Comment: @phoog Not a duplicate. **Here** the OP reported to the police but not the embassy, **there** the OP reported to the embassy.

Comment: @phoog The question you are linking to is not a duplicate. In the linked question, the lost visa was reported to the US embassy. In this question, passportloser clearly states that he has *not* reported a loss of the visa to the US authorities.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the Visa is unexpired and undamaged [you can travel with it](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html) to enter the US. You will need to present both passports when entering the country.

Comment: How do you derive that from the page you are linking to?