# Lost and found my indian passport with US Visa

Tags: usa, passports, lost-documents

I had lost my Indian passport with a US visa and later filed an FIR and got a new indian passport but before reporting to the US embassy i found my lost passport, can I travel with both my passports to the US as the US visa in my lost and found passport is still in force?

### note: I did not report my lost visa to the embassy as I found it before reporting.

@ Patricia Shanahan, there was no such information given to me regarding returning it back.

---

@ Newton, thanks man, that information was for expired passport and not for lost and found passport, I have to feel that the found passport will be expired and I can travel with the valid visa only. @DumbCoder 3, that is when you reported it to the Embassy but I found the passport before informing them.

Comment: When you got the replacement were you told to turn in the old passport if you found it?

Comment: generally, like if a passport expires and you get a new one, but your old passport has valid visas, you can show the valid visas on the old passport while travelling. Better check with the local US embassy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost passport with a valid visa on it, replaced passport, then found it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78455/lost-passport-with-a-valid-visa-on-it-replaced-passport-then-found-it)

Comment: @DumbCoder This is not a duplicate of that question. That question says the loss was reported to the US, and the answer there is quite explicit that, because the loss was reported to the US, the visa was cancelled. In the case of this question, the loss was not reported to the US, so the answer there doesn't apply.

Comment: What is an FIR?

Answer (score 3):

When you find the old passport, you should quickly bring it to the issuer authority (or police).

Lost passport are usually considered stolen, so they are stored in invalid passport databases.  By having it (or worst, by using it) you get a lot of trouble.

You should care much more about passport (not lose it). It is a security and safety hazard. (because of possible use for criminal activities, which include impersonating you for bank credit).

Answer (score 2):

I got to travel with this situation and I was let through. The lost and found passport is considered as expired in this case and you can travel if you did not report the visa being lost.